# Как правильно использовать функцию set_symmetric_difference

Tags: c++, алгоритм, xcode

Код, приведенный на скрине, компилятор не пропускает. Понял, что функция не может записать значения в diff

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не

```
diff.begin()
```

а

```
std::inserter(diff)
```

И если все остальное написано правильно, то...

И еще - не надо сюда картинки отправлять, это не журнал "Веселые картинки", всегда давайте текст. Оно и проще, кстати...

Comment: Разве не просто `inserter`? В `set` же нет метода `push_back`.

Comment: @EOF Спасибо за замечание!